# How to identify Launch Activity name?

Tags: android, github, keyboard, appium

I have seen app activity name through appium or APK Info app but still confusing. 
Not abale to identify right activity name. 
Please share your views.

Comment: What exactly do you want keyboard name or activity name??

Comment: Launch Activity Name

Comment: If you want to know which is the current keyboard ur device is using i can help you with that also if u want.As ur question says identify keyboard

Answer (score 0):

using ./aapt dum badging apkfilelocation
Exp: Type "./aapt dum badging ../../../../../Desktop/Consumer.apk "